# Very simple program in fortran giving me a segmentation fault. Very confused

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I've been going crazy trying to read in some data into arrays in my simple program. I cannot work out why I am getting a segmentation fault. My code begins:

```
program guess_input
implicit none

CHARACTER*2, allocatable, dimension(:) :: element
double precision, allocatable, dimension(:,:)      :: xyzq
INTEGER, allocatable, dimension(:)                 :: label,cs_num, br_num, xx_num
real, allocatable, dimension(:)                    :: distance
real, allocatable, dimension(:)                    :: ep
INTEGER                                :: stat, numatom, i, j
CHARACTER*80  :: line

numatom = 61502
allocate(element(numatom))
allocate(xyzq(4,numatom))
allocate(label(numatom))

OPEN(UNIT=22,FILE='EMBQ_EPF.OUT',iostat=stat)
If(stat.ne.0) Stop "File not found"

!Read in the input into two arrays

do i=1,numatom
READ(22,'(A)') line
READ(line, *) xyzq(1,i), xyzq(2,i), xyzq(3,i), xyzq(4,i), label(i)
enddo
CLOSE(22)

!Define element type in parallel array based on the charge 
do i=1,numatom
if(xyzq(4,i) == 1.00) then
            element(i) = 'Cs'
elseif(xyzq(4,i) == -1.00) then
            element(i) = 'Br'
else
        element(i) = 'XX'
    endif
 enddo

 OPEN(33, FILE='element.out')
 do i=1,numatom
 write(33,*) element(i)
 enddo

 end program guess_input
```

I have tried isolating the fault but I really cannot work out what is going wrong.

Any help is would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It would be hard to guess without an input file. I've generated some fake input (in python: `for i in xrange(61502): fd.write("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n" % (1, -1, -1, -1+i%5, '22'))`), works fine.

Comment: Can you tell us what line it segfaults on? Using GDB or something?

Comment: Since you have only posted part of your code and you have not identified the line or block where the segmentation fault occurs can you assure us that the fragment you have posted causes a segmentation fault so that we don't waste our time looking for the fault in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest compiling with run-time subscript checking, if you haven't done so all ready.   One likely cause of a segmentation fault is a subscript error.  It is helpful during debugging to use maximum compiler diagnostics.  With gfortran: `-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace`.    With ifort: `-O2  -stand f03    -assume realloc_lhs  -check all  -traceback  -warn all  -fstack-protector  -assume protect_parens  -implicitnone`.    `-fcheck=all` and `-check all` include run-time subscript checking; just run-time subscript checking can be selected if desired -- consult the compiler documentation.

Also: exact comparisons to floating point values are risky.  I suggest either converting xyzq to an integer variable or testing to a range:

```
if( abs (xyzq(4,i) - 1.00) < 0.01 ) then
```

Comment: `1.0` is exactly representable in singe and double precision IEEE 745 but your note still holds true. +1

Answer (score 1):

To find the cause of a segmentation fault you may use the *memcheck* tool of [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). The syntax is quite simple:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full <binary> <arguments>
```

This tool should provide you with the exact line in the source code where [memory-management problems](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) occur.

Comment: Unlike C/C++, Fortran doesn't lose track of memory allocations and most F90+ implementations use array descriptors, which allows them to perform run-time bounds checking if necessary. Using `valgrind` is a bit of an overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is your compiler smart enough to know you mean "numatom" and "i" to be 4-byte integers?  If not, and it assumes you mean "INTEGER" to be 2-bytes long, you'll be delving into the mysterious world of negative memory space.

Comment: Although the Fortran standard doesn't specify the size of the default `INTEGER` kind, I doubt that there are modern Fortran processors that use 16-bit integers by default (unless he is using some old 16-bit DOS processor...)